# Move folder into another folder using sudo

Tags: sudo, mv

I'm trying to move a folder into another folder with sudo. (I'm a beginner!) I tried this:

```
sudo mv /home/mirko/Documenti/Bifurcation%20%20Control/PROPAC/ProPac_53  /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.0/AddOns/Applications/ProPac_5/
```

And receive this error message: "nonexistent directory".

Comment: Indeed the first one does not exist, since you forgot to start with a /. You can simply drag the directory on to the terminal to prevent typos.

Comment: I'm still having the same problem! @JacobVlijm

Comment: I dont think that you can use %20 to represent a space. I think that you should either simply enclose the whole file name in "double quotes" or use a backslash character to protect a space (use `Bifurcation\ \ Control` instead of `Bifurcation%20%20Control`

Comment: I tried using "/home/mirko/Documenti/Bifurcation%20%20Control/PROPAC/ProPac_53" but it doesn't work. I tried with \ but it doesn't work either. @NickSillito

Comment: @NickSillito I think the reason is that indeed the folder has two spaces. I have renamed the folder and it works now.

Comment: Hi @NickSillito could you make it an answer? (Single quotes suffice). I'll vote for it if you do :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your question, you use `%20`to represent a space, which isn't understood by the shell. There are a number of ways to include spaces in a command line, the easiest one is to include them in double quotes.

The following command should work for you:

```
sudo mv "/home/mirko/Documenti/Bifurcation  Control/PROPAC/ProPac_53"  /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.0/AddOns/Applications/ProPac_5/
```

Comment: Double quotes work here, but the easiest way is *single quotes* (`'`), since [the rules for single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes) are simple: text after an unquoted `'` is interpreted literally until the next `'`. `'` and `"` both quote spaces but, with other characters, [the rules for double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes) are quite complex. For example, whether ```\``` is special in double quotes (and, if so, how it is treated) depends on the character that follows it.